# DateTime property in EntityFramework Core incorrectly adds data to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework-core

I have a DateTime property on the model:

```
public class OrderTimeModel
    {
    DateTime orderTime;

    public DateTime OrderTime { get { return orderTime; } set { orderTime = DateTime.Now; } }
    }
```

I have the wrong date and time in SQL Server: 01.01.0001 0:00:00

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want something like:

```
public DateTime OrderTime { get; set } = DateTime.Now;
```

Because set is not the default value, it is what you set it with.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I found where I made a mistake.

```
public class OrderTimeModel
{
public DateTime orderTime = DateTime.Now;
public DateTime OrderTime { get { return orderTime; } set { orderTime = value; }
}
```